# Use column as regex pattern with QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm trying to use a column as a regular expression to match against a user provided string, but can't figure out how to do it with QueryDSL. Mostly I can't figure out how to put the user supplied string on the lefthand side of the expression.

Basically I'm looking to do something similar to the following, where `~` is my databases symbol for regex matching…

```sql
SELECT * FROM thing WHERE 'user supplied string' ~ thing.match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works

```
Expressions.predicate(Ops.MATCHES, Expressions.constant(...), path)
```

Comment: I'm going to make this as correct because it seems to be the correct answer with current version of QueryDSL. However I'm still on 3.2.4, and stringOperation(…) takes an `Operator<? super String>` operator and Ops.MATCHES is `Operator<Boolean>` so that didn't work for me.

Comment: I fixed the API usage

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the best way, but the only solution I was able to get working was to subclass `StringExpression`

```java
class ConstantExpression extends StringExpression {
  private Constant<String> constant;

  static public ConstantExpression create(String constant) {
     return new ConstantExpression(new ConstantImpl<String>(constant);
  }

  public ConstantExpression(Constant<String> mixin) {
     super(mixin);
     constant = mixin;
  }

  public <R,C> R accept(Visitor<R,C> v, C context) {
     return v.visit(constnat, context);
  }
}
```

Then I was able to use that as the lefthand side of the equation…

```java
createJPAQueryFactory().from(qthing)
    .where(ConstantExpression.create("user supplied…").like(thing.match)
```